# How to get a custom message on fail login credentials in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I use this code to check user credentials, but I can't figure how to change the code to get an error message when credentials fail. Used redirect and so on, but show nothing....

```
 public function loginWithCredentials(Request $request) {

    $signinEmail = $request->input('email');
    $signinPassword = $request->input('password');

    $user = new Users();
    $errors = new MessageBag;
    $user = $user
                ->where('email', '=', $signinEmail)
                ->get()->first();

    if(empty($user)) {
        $errors->add('error', 'Invalid credentials!');
        return json_encode([
                'error'=>true,
                'messages'=>$errors
        ]);
    }
    $userdata = $user->toArray();


    if(md5($signinPassword) != $userdata['password']) {
        $errors->add('error', 'Invalid credentials!');

        return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
    }

    Session::put('user',$userdata);
    $errors->add('message0', 'Welcome ' . strtoupper($userdata['username']) . '!');


}
```

Now it just simple redirects me to a white page with the "invalid credentials" message. I want the message to be on login page.

Answer (score 2):

Your code you has some flaws, consider fixing it.

- Why are you mixing json response with html response?
- Consider using `bcrypt()` for [hashing](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/hashing) your users passwords instead `md5()`.
- Add some sort of validation, Laravel has the built in validation.
- Laravel ships with easy use login auth, take a look at.

So in your code needs some changes here it is:

```php
public function loginWithCredentials(Request $request) {

    $signinEmail = $request->input('email');
    $signinPassword = $request->input('password');

    $user = new Users();
    $user = $user
        ->where('email', '=', $signinEmail)
        ->get()->first();


    if(empty($user) || md5($signinPassword) != $user->password) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Invalid credentials!');
    }

    $userdata = $user->toArray();

    Session::put('user', $userdata);
    return view('view.name')->with('message', 'Welcome ' . strtoupper($userdata['username']) . '!');
}
```

Then in your view you write the success message like so:

```html
@if (session('message'))
 <div class="alert alert-success">
   {{ session('message') }}
 </div>
@endif
```

this example is using blade, but should be similar to other views.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to override **AuthenticatesUsers Trait** method named **sendFailedLoginResponse** like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
     use AuthenticatesUsers;

     ...

     protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
     {
          throw ValidationException::withMessages([
               'your array key' => ['Place your custom message here'],
          ]);
     }

     ...
}
```

That's It!

I hope this will help you. :)